# Get name of column from PowerShell sql query

Tags: sql, .net, powershell

I'm running a sql query from PowerShell. I can get the row data and the number of columns correctly, but I need to gather the name of the columns from the sql table generated in my query. For example, if my table looked like this:

```
    Column1    Column2   
1 |row1Item1 |row1Item2 |
2 |row2Item1 |row2Item2 |
3 |row3Item1 |row3Item2 |
```

Then the values I need are "Column1", "Column2". The code I have below will tell me that there are 2 columns, but I don't know how to get the names of those columns.

```
$cmd = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sqlquery, $connection)
$connection.Open()
$reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
$reader.FieldCount   #returns the number of columns --> 2
```

Comment: in your sql query, you should already know columns are your returning. because the syntax of sql statement is select [column_name] from [table_name].

Comment: Not if the sql query is like `select * from table`. If I write the query this way then I don't explicitly know the column names until the resulting table is generated. I need for PowerShell to be able to get the column names.

Comment: select * will return all the columns from a table. so you still know what columns you are returning. the table you are using is a permanent table or temp table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SqlDataAdapter.Fill()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.fill(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a reader. This way you can have the script populate a `DataTable` object which will retain the column names:

```
$cmd = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sqlquery, $SqlConnection)
$SqlConnection.Open()

# Create adapter, associate with command
$Adapter = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter]::new($cmd)

# Create empty DataTable
$DataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

# Fill datatable based on query
$Adapter.Fill($DataTable)

$DataTable.Rows[0] # returns a DataRow object with correct column names
```

Comment: Okay, so from where you left off, I added the line: `$DataTable.Coulmns[0].ColumnName` to return "Column1" from the table. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try look for

```
$table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
```

Something similiar is in C# its better for accessing the table that you get from the query.

Hope it helps!

Edit:
In c# its like this

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString); 

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(); 

SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand(); 

cmd.CommandText = SQL; 

da.SelectCommand = cmd; 

DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 

conn.Open(); 

da.Fill(ds); 
conn.Close();return ds;
```

Comment: How is this used?